# Running a custom script in Android after boot

Tags: android, bash, android-source, selinux

I have a script which I want to run after some time of Android boot. I've made following changes:

in init.rc

```
service bootscript /system/bin/sh /system/bin/bootscript
    class late_start
    user root
    group root
    oneshot
```

in makefile:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
       device/qcom/msm8953_32/bootscript:system/bin/bootscript
```

After that when I built and flash, I was getting following error in dmesg,

```
[   59.243265] init: service bootscript does not have a SELinux domain defined
```

in system/sepolicy/private/file_contexts

```
   /system/bin/bootscript          --      u:object_r:shell_exec:s0
```

I'm still getting this error, what else I shall add? I've tried finding on internet, [I found steps where they add it init_daemon_domain()](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy), is it same thing as that? Because I don't see any PRODUCT_COPY_FILES step there so I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

You should not lable bootscript with shell_exec. There is not an rule init_daemon_domain(shell).

So you should follow [the example](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials).

1. Define an new domain, and add init transition rule.

```
type foo, domain;
type foo_exec, exec_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(foo)
```

2. Lable you file with new label.

```
/system/bin/bootscript          --      u:object_r:foo_exec:s0
```

init_daemon_domain(foo) means a file with foo_exec lable will be tranlate from init to foo domain.